# Memoir with chapterstyle "veelo": black box also for unnumbered chapters

Tags: memoir

I'm using the memoir class with chapter style "veelo", which renders black boxes for numbered chapters:

[image]

But not for unnumbered chapters:

[image]

Is there a way to get these boxes also for unnumbered chapters? (preferably in the same line as the caption)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\addtodef\chs@veelo{}{
   \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
     \chapnamefont%
     \makebox[0pt][l]{%
       \hspace{.8em}%
       \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont \phantom{1}}%
       \hspace{.8em}% <-- there was a left over space 
       \rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}%
     }%
     \afterchapternum
   }%
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{veelo}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is almost perfect. The "black box" is not on the same line as the chapter title though. Can that be fixed somehow?

Comment: It is in the exact same spot every time. the unstarred version should not be placed in a different position. That will look strange (the box jumping up and down). It ought to be doable. But I do not have the time for it.

Comment: @Niko, note there was a bug in my code, the two black boxes was not exactly the same with, fixed now.